# Selecting each td by attribute name, then gives 'undefined' for the attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery, attr

I have a table with a td in it like so:

```
<td age="123">0</td>
```

Using jQuery, the following JavaScript

```
$('td[age]').each(function(){
    console.log($('this').attr('age'));
});
```

prints 'undefined' to the console in Chrome.

Why is it not printing "123"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where you have

```
$('this')
```

You should instead have

```
$(this)
```

Answer (score 2):

**working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/SZSr5/

```
$('td[age]').each(function(){
    alert($(this).html());
});​
```